# git push is not working with git-for-window

Tags: git, git-push

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6wyK.png)

Without any errors  take forever.

When i close the gitbash window, it comes out as shown above.

Comment: Note: The duplicate doesn't have a good solution yet, but this is pretty clearly the same problem. This seems to be a new bug, introduced by some recent change to Git, Windows, Git-for-Windows, or some combination of some or all of these.

Comment: The above solution does not solve it.